# Lookup attribute value R

Tags: r, attributes

I have a .csv file:

```
ID; attribute1; attribute2; attribute3
1; 2; 3; 4
2; 7; 8; 3
3; 4; 6; 4
4; 2; 3; 4
```

In a separate word document I have a list explaining what each value means e.g.

Attribute 1:

2 Hello

4 Goodbye

7 Example

When I read and then plot the data with r, how can I lookup what the actual value is for each attribute (e.g. "Hello", "Goodbye", "Example")?  Rather than just having the numbers display on the plot (e.g. "2", "4", "7").

Comment: I'd suggest you take your table in Word and convert it to something in CSV, ala `attribute;detail\n2;Hello\n4;Goodbye\n7;Example\n`. At that point, you can use `merge` or `left_join` to bring in the name. If you want more, you're going to need to explain a lot more of your example, as it is not clear what you are doing in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is make the lookup information (what you have in the Word doc) into a dataframe, and merge it with your original dataframe. If the lookup information is small, like in your post, you can just type it into `data.frame`; otherwise, make a csv file of it & read it into R.

Here are two ways, one with `inner_join` from `dplyr`, one with `merge` from base R. Both join dataframes based on the values in `attribute1`.

**Edit**: @r2evans made a good point that `left_join` is more appropriate, because it ensures you don't lose observations just because they have an attribute that isn't included in the lookup table. Changing both examples to left joins.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- "ID; attribute1; attribute2; attribute3
1; 2; 3; 4
2; 7; 8; 3
3; 4; 6; 4
4; 2; 3; 4" %>%
    read_delim("; ", trim_ws = T)

lookup <- data.frame(
    attribute1 = c(2, 4, 7),
    attr1_text = c("Hello", "Goodbye", "Example")
)

left_join(df, lookup, by = "attribute1")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>      ID attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attr1_text
#>   <int>      <dbl>      <int>      <int> <fct>     
#> 1     1         2.          3          4 Hello     
#> 2     2         7.          8          3 Example   
#> 3     3         4.          6          4 Goodbye   
#> 4     4         2.          3          4 Hello

merge(df, lookup, by = "attribute1", all.x = T)
#>   attribute1 ID attribute2 attribute3 attr1_text
#> 1          2  1          3          4      Hello
#> 2          2  4          3          4      Hello
#> 3          4  3          6          4    Goodbye
#> 4          7  2          8          3    Example
```

Created on 2018-04-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I suggest `left_join` vice `inner_join`: I'd much rather see an `NA` in my plot and know that I'm missing a label, than not notice that my label-less numbers were all removed. Similarly, `merge(..., all.x=TRUE)`.

Comment: @r2evans Word, good point. `left_join` is usually my default, especially in a case like this...I don't even know what I was thinking!